# How to apply Single annotation on multiple variables?

Tags: java, variables, annotations

I am rookie in `Java Annotation` and have been searching for applying single `annotation` on multiple variable simultaneously.

## Code:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

   private ObjectId id;

   @NotNull
   private String email;
   private String imageURL;
   private String authToken;

   private Date createdDate;
   private Date updateDate;
   private boolean isActivated;
   private int credits;

   .....getter/Setter Method
```

I want to apply `@NotNull` property on `email`, `imageURL` and `authToken` too. I can do it by  writing `@NotNull` to each `variable` but not preferring. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NotNull annotation can be applied at element not at group of elements.

> JavaDoc: The annotated element must not be null. Accepts any type.

If you really want to get away with boiler plate code, you can use frameworks like Lombok which can help you to certain extent.

Link : http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html

OR you can use reflection to validate all the method.

```
for (Field f : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
  f.setAccessible(true); // optional
  if (f.get(obj) == null) {
     f.set(obj, getDefaultValueForType(f.getType()));
     // OR throw error
  }
}
```

Comment: What about for other references like `@DBRef`? I also didn't find any information on it.

Comment: I didn't get your question, can you elaborate 'What about for other references like @DBRef?'

Comment: As the blog stated that we can't apply `@NotNull` annotation on a group of Element. Does it only apply on `@NotNull`  annotation or all of them?

Comment: It applies to '@NotNull' annotation. As I know there is no annotation which can be applied on all declared fields as you are expecting. Hibernate validation is one matured validation framework you can look at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support multiple annotation of this type. But you can write something like this

- Create a class with annotated field.
- Create setters and getters to access the field.
- Create all your name,email field as instance of this class.

This way fields will implicitly annotated as NotNull.

```
            public class NotNullString {
                @NotNull
                String str;
                public void set(String str)
                {
                    this.str = str;
                }
                public String get()
                {
                    return this.str;
                }
            }

            NotNullString name;
            NotNullString email;
```